# Get all elements of array in query laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to loop in an array but when it comes to the query it gets only the first element, so a little help would be very important.

```
 $data = Offers::whereIn('id_business', $business_id_array)
                    ->where([
                        'visible' => 'yes',
                        'delete' => 'no'
                    ])
                    ->where('end_date', '>=', date('Y-m-d h:m:i'))
                    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                    ->get();

                $data=array($data);

                foreach($data as $key => $item) {
                    $offers = DB::select('the data i need to get WHERE o.`id` = ' . $item[$key]['id']);


                }
```

and this is my problem in here, It gets only the id of the first element

```
o.`id` = ' . $item[$key]['id']
```

Comment: Try `$item->id` in your loop.

Comment: @AmitGupta no man, it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you have return the view in side the foreach loop, so it only loop through the first item and return. What you can do with this case is

```
$data = Offers::whereIn('id_business', $business_id_array)...->get()->toArray();
$offers = array_map(function($item){
     $offer = DB::select('the data i need to get WHERE o.`id` = ?', [$item->id]);  
     return $offer;
},$data);
return view(....,['offers' =>$offers]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you do not need to cast the `$data` to an array - it will get returned as a collection, which you can iterate through like an array. So you'll be able to use something like this

```
$offers = Offers::whereIn('id_business', $business_id_array)...->get();

foreach ($offers as $offer) {
    $moreData = DB::select('the data i need to get WHERE o.`id` = ?', [$offer->id]);
}
```

Comment: it still get only one id, only the first one, while i get 4 elements as array

Comment: use `foreach ($offers->items as $offer)` instead

Comment: @ayip you mean   foreach ($offers as $items=>$offer)

Comment: no, use either `foreach ($offers->items as $offer)` or if it gives any errors, use `foreach ($offers->getItems() as $offer)`

Comment: @User154584 do you do anything with  $moreData  inside the loop beside running the query?

Comment: @PhongTran no I only get the elements and then return the view

Comment: @User154584 did you get elements outside the loop or inside the loop?

Comment: @PhongTran inside the for each loop

Comment: @ayip in both cases laravel get an error, and in the case of this answer in foreach it get only the first element of array

Comment: @User154584 and do you return the view inside the loop too ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146274/discussion-between-user154584-and-phong-tran).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are using the id from one table, to get the associated data from another table.

Should there not be a relationship in place, between the two tables?

The answer from @Chris G looks correct, maybe dd($offers) to be certain what is in there.

Mick

Comment: it get an array when like this :
Collection {#256 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => Offers {#255 ▶}
    1 => Offers {#254 ▶}
    2 => Offers {#253 ▶}
    3 => Offers {#252 ▶}
  ]
}

Comment: and inside each of this arrays I need to get the ID